# Spring DB connectivity: Timeout of 30000ms encountered waiting for connection

Tags: spring-boot

We are facing an issue related to Spring database connectivity waiting timeout. As you are aware, by default spring boot waits till 30000ms for database connection (in case of db connectivity failure).

We had one requirement of data forwarding even though db connectivity is not available, so we implemented the requirement, but we are facing delay in data forwarding approx 30sec to 1-minute.

What we understood is that our main thread is trying to get the db connection and waiting at least till 30000ms to acquire the DB connection, now due to this, other processes which are not having any relation with database are getting stuck, and each process is getting executed after 30 seconds or more.

Do we have any property of spring boot or any other way to reduce this waiting time by 10000ms.

We tried, below two properties, but it didn't work out for us.

hibernate.pooling.connectionTestStatement = SELECT 1,

hibernate.pooling.idleTimeout = 10000